# How to detect when material UI autocomplete popover is opened

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I have 4000 items in autocomplete. It takes lot of time to open the popover. I want to show a spinner until the popover is shown to user.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks